# Calculation in excel to take place (once) on (a specific date) and result to stay when date has passed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to get a result, let’s say the total of A1 - A10, at the end of January on the 31st in cell B1. That's easy enough, IF  = 31/1/17 etc. But I need this figure to remain frozen at that result and not change as A1 - A10 changes in value or when today is beyond that date.

Is this possible, as I will need to this on 10 columns of a 12-month period?

Comment: Best method is vba in a worksheet change event.

Comment: are you using both excel 2010 and 2007 ?

Answer (score -1):

@Rob, suppose you have data in range A1 to A10, and you want to calculate the total automatically when Current date will 31/01/2017 and for example you have written this formula on 15/01/2017.

Write any where in blank cell like in D1 the calculation date value which is 31/01/2017. And in A11 write any of the below written formula.

=IF(TODAY()=D1,SUM(A1:A10),"Out of Date")

=SUMPRODUCT(--(D1=TODAY())*A1:A10)

As soon the Current date will match the calculation date Excel will produce Sum in A11.

**Now the next step**, as you have written you want the result remain in the Cell even the date expires or if you change the values in data range A1 to A10.

**For this the simplest tricky solution** is **Copy the cell A11**, place pointer in A11 only and **click Paste Special** and **hit the option Value**. You find the same value in A11 or your answer will remain same in any conditions.

Reason behind this,, when you Copy & Paste the VALUE, Excel will remove the Formula from the cell A11.

Hope the help you, no need to think for any kind of VBA code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, the second part of your suggestion requires a manual intervention, but I need this to be automatic.
Thanks
Rob

Answer (score -1):

**@Rob**, purposely I've not posted the automate method but since you are so disparate so, here I brought the simple VBA code will Sum the data range if the **key Cell(D1)** has Current date.

Also this code will Convert the cell for the Value as you demanded that finally the Result must remain unchanged.

**NB:** You can use this code with Command Button click Event or as Worksheet Change Event. Here for the example I've used the Command Button. Hope this help you & this time you Vote Positive to my answer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


 Range("A11").Value = "=IF(ISBLANK(D1),0,IF(D1=TODAY(),SUM(A1:A10)))"


  Range("A11").Copy

  Range("A11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really unable to understand what is wrong with the above VBA code and some body has voted negative,,!!! Man answer if you read this comment.

Comment: Hi Rajesh - I did not leave the negative feedback, but it may be because it is still a manual process I need this to be fully automatic without the need for pressing a command button on the day before the data changes.

Comment: @Rob, you are mistaken, what I've shown you through VBA code is doing both,,, writing the Formula and clears the Cell and remember it was the Query you posted,!!